# How do I mock InlineScript?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

Here is my service I'd like to test :

```
class AffairesJSService {
    private $inlineScript;
    private $url;
    private $sBasepath;

    public function __construct($inlineScript, $url, $sBasepath)
    {
        $this->inlineScript = $inlineScript;
        $this->url          = $url;
        $this->sBasepath    = $sBasepath;
    }

    public function inject($aParams)
    {
        $url = $this->url;
        $containerRoutes = new Container('IntraRouteListAffaires');

        $sEtatAffaire    = $containerRoutes->sEtatAffaire !== null    ? $containerRoutes->sEtatAffaire    : 'EN_COURS';
        $iIdPrestation   = $containerRoutes->iIdPrestation !== null   ? $containerRoutes->iIdPrestation   : 0;
        $iIdCentreProfit = $containerRoutes->iIdCentreProfit !== null ? $containerRoutes->iIdCentreProfit : 0;

        $this->inlineScript->appendFile($this->sBasepath . $aParams["myfile"]);

        $sUrlListContrats = $url('module/action', ['idaffaire' => $aParams['idaffaire']]);

        $this->inlineScript->captureStart();
            echo <<<JS
            loadPanelContrats('$sUrlListContrats'); JS;
            $this->inlineScript->captureEnd();
    } }
```

Well, this is my test but i don't know how to mock InlineScripts and declare appendFile :

```
class AffairesJSServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var MyService
     */
    private $myService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $mockUrl = $this->getMock('Zend\View\Helper\Url\Url', array(), array(), '', false);

        $inlineScript = $this->getMock('Zend\View\Helper\InlineScript\InlineScript', array(), array(), '', false);

        $sBasepath = "/my/path";

        $this->myService = new AffairesJSService(
            $inlineScript,
            $mockUrl,
            $sBasepath,
        );
    }

    public function testInject()
    {
        $aParams = array();
        //$aParams["myfile"] = 'myfile';
        $this->myService->inject($aParams);
    }
```

Could you please help ? The most problemetic question is how to mock specific zf2 methods. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? Your code looks fine to me

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function appendFile() on a non-object

Comment: I think I must add this method and the return value to my mock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fluent syntax you can do the following. All the methods of the mock will do nothing and return null :

```
$inlineScript = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\View\Helper\InlineScript\InlineScript')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
```

If you only want to mock specific methods, you can specify it with the `setMethods()` method :

```
$inlineScript = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\View\Helper\InlineScript\InlineScript')
    ->setMethods(['appendFile'])
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
```

Comment: Thanks but this tells me that $this->inlineScript is not an object ... :/

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump what's getting passed to your object? IF you had `var_dump($this->inlineScript)` in your class constructor, what do you see?

Comment: object(Mock_InlineScript_6e8bcf5b)#6587 (2) {
["__phpunit_invocationMocker":"Mock_InlineScript_6e8bcf5b":private]=> NULL
["__phpunit_originalObject":"Mock_InlineScript_6e8bcf5b":private]=> NULL }

Comment: Well I think InlineScript is not 'mockable' so I use a new instance of inlinescript instead ... but i've got a problem with url so i close this subject and create a new one ...